# Stop execution of ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net, application-start

In my Application_Start() method, how can I stop the execution of the ASP.NET application when certain conditions are not met?

Throwing an exception doesn't appear to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i don't think that's possible; even if you could 'abort' the startup, the next attempt to access a URL from the site would try to start it again

perhaps a static variable could be used to signal go/no-go, and begin_request could redirect to a placeholder page instead?

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a [COM API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524713.aspx) that you can use for IIS administration.  I think I'd try Environment.Exit() first, though.

Comment: Environment.Exit() apparently also kills IIS and the entire AppPool. I had to restart both the Management Console and the AppPool that my application was running in before IIS would function correctly again.

Answer (score 0):

Do something that throws an unhandled error.  Maybe throwing an Exception would be enough.