# How can I stop an ASP.NET website from loading depending on a certain condition?

Tags: asp.net

How can i stop asp.net website?
I want check some condition and after that if something's wrong then stop website from loading.

Comment: What exactly do you want to check?

Comment: What do you mean by stop website from loading?

Comment: @Anuraj : stop website from loading  = nothing happend? is this possible? or i should do somthing else

Comment: You want to stop the execution of Page_Load event? What you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @Anuraj : stop the execution of application_Start!! again if it this possible.

Comment: @Raika: Check this SO link  : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/380043/stop-execution-of-asp-net-application

Comment: Maybe if you have a login screen, you can check for your condition and disable the login activity!

Comment: so it's impossbile. i neeed Redirect to some page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually want to redirect to another page in case of an exception.

Answer (score 5):

You could try the code.

```
Response.End()
```

Comment: but isn't it going to cause a "Thread was being aborted." exception in that case?